# access form won't update while combobox is being edited, must move to next record

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a continuous form with a list of comboboxes, pic here:

[image]

As you can see there is a small pencil on the left side of the access form to display that the current record in the form is being edited. I need to change this to a triangle so the other forms update properly with a button. Is there VBA to "lose focus" or change the pencil to a black triangle? I tried move to next record but for some strange reason it crashed. In addition it was fairly complex because I had to add logic if the user was on the last record, since it would throw an error because it can't go to next record on the last record. My vba is below (currently crashes access for some reason)

```
with recordset
if .recordcount=1 then
docmd.gotorecord record:=acfirst

elseif .absoluteposition = .recordcount - 1 then
docmd.gotorecord record:=acprevious
docmd.gotorecord record:=acnext
else
docmd.gotorecord record:=acnext
docmd.gotorecord record:=acprevious
end if
end with
end sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way is to save:

```
 If Me.Dirty Then
     Me.Dirty = False
 End If
```

Pick a suitable event.

If Access is crashing, it usually means you need to back-up, compact and repair, and decompile.

Comment: After change may not be a good idea if your users are given to typing into the combo. After change will occur with every letter typed.

Comment: Confirmed this works perfectly, thanks a bunch. Specifically it worked under the after update event, and not the change event (because like you mentioned it activates after every letter typed)